# How to select only one checkbox when data comes from database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to give permission to the user to select only one check box.

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select * from products where id='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

$formats = explode(";", $jfeta['formats']);

<div class="">
    <?php foreach($formats as $v){ ?>
        <label style="line-height: 1.25em;display: block;width: 100px;margin-right: 10px;float: left;">                         
            <div class="fomat_buttons" style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da;">                             
            <input class="format_cheks" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $v; ?>" style="visibility:hidden;"/>              
                <span style="margin:-17px auto auto 0px;display:block;"><?php echo $v; ?></span>                            
            </div>                      
        </label>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to give permission to the user to select only one check box

Sounds like you want a radio button group, not checkboxes.

```
<input class="format_cheks" type="radio" name="format_cheks" value="<?php echo $v; ?>" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
<!-- Changes here ---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     -->
```

The browser will automatically deselect any other `name="format_cheks"` radio button when the user checks one of the others. When the form is submitted, only *one* `format_cheks` field is sent, with the value of the checked radio button (if any).

```html
<div><label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="1"> One</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="2"> Two</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="3"> Three</label></div>
```